# Delayed job process running, has an item in queue, still doesn't run (didn't fail either)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm simply trying to run a function in the background, using delayed_job as instructed by this guide: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

I've done the following:

1. Included `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` in my Gemfile.
2. Added `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job` to my `config/application.rb` file.
3. Ran `rails generate delayed_job:active_record` and `rake db:migrate` from the console.

Now when I go to a function that used to work, such as:

```
t = Test.new(@test)
t.start
```

and replace the second line with

```
t.delay.start
```

I can see that the job has been added successfully into the Delayed Job table. However, NOTHING happens. It never runs. It never even fails. I've verified that `bin/delayed_job` is indeed running (according to `ps aux | grep -i delay`)

But nothing ever runs. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what the delayed job table looks like:

[image]

I see that the job is locked, but have no idea what that means. I cleared the lock by running `DelayedJob.all.update(locked_at: nil, locked_by: nil)`.

Comment: I don't remember which columns exactly but you can find information if a job was, wasn't or will be executed; and if it was executed and failed, an error message on delayed_job's table. Maybe you can find useful information there!

Comment: I see that the job is locked, but that's it. Going to update a screenshot with the job details.

Comment: Can you try running the job in foreground to check the output? First stop the current instance with: `bin/delayed_job stop` and then execute `bin/delayed_job run --exit-on-complete`

Comment: When I run this, it actually works.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you include the configuration options used (config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb) and the definition of Test

Comment: I ended up just using sidekiq instead. I haven't configured anything in the initializers so it should have been default (or non-existent). I appreciate your help!